# Get first and last elements from list according to enumerate list Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have column in Pandas full of lists. Each row looks like:

```
row_1 = [7, 8, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
row_2 = [7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
...
row_n = [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
```

And I need to get boundary values and insert them to the tuple, e.g.

```
full_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ...,35]
```

and according to the list above find first and last values:

```
row_tuple_1 = [(7, 8), (14, 23)]
row_tuple_2 = [(7, 9), (15, 19)]
...
row_tuple_n = [(27, 35)]
```

Is there a way to do that?

**Upd1:**

Imagine that `full_list` is how `row_1` should look's like. But it's not.

Another option to write `row_1` is:

```
row_1 = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 8, np.nan, 
np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, np.nan, ...]
```

So `(start, end)` tuple should be `(7, 8)` and `(14, 23)`

Comment: I don't know anything about Pandas, but in general, the first item in a list is `mylist[0]` and the last item is `mylist[-1]`.  However, your example is confusing -- how did you get `(14, 23)` as the second value in `row_tuple_1`?  I see that `23` is the last value in `row_1`, but where did `14` come from?

Comment: ```14``` is there third value of  ```row_1```. And that's a thing, I need to get "last" value, that not actually last.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: Yes, I see that `14` is the third item in `row_1`, but why does it belong in `row_tuple_1`?  Why does `row_tuple_1` contain the first and second, and third and last, items from `row_1`?

Comment: _I need to get "last" value, that not actually last_ We have no idea what that means.  Please explain, in detail.

Comment: Added more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally know what you need , we need using `groupby` for each row

```
def func(x):
    s=pd.Series(x)
    return s.groupby(s.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).agg(['first','last']).values.tolist()
df.L.apply(func)
Out[145]: 
0    [[7, 8], [14, 23]]
1    [[7, 9], [15, 19]]
2            [[27, 35]]
Name: L, dtype: object
```